# Django 2.0: Get queries dynamically from search

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

I am new to Django framework and as a practice project I am trying to build an ecommerce website using Django. I have a class based view for my search page. I wrote the view to get the query for a particular query:

**views.py**

```
class SearchProductView(ListView):  
    template_name = "template.html"
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(title__icontains='book')
    print(queryset)
```

I would like to know how I can write a function to get the search queries dynamically. For e.g.: If i search `book`, then my `queryset` should contain all things about `book` and if I search `car`, then I should get all things about `car`.

**template.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} 
<div class='row'>
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <div class='col'>
        {{ forloop.counter }}
        {% include 'products/snippets/card.html' with instance=object %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>  
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import SearchProductView

app_name = 'search'

urlpatterns = [   
    path('', SearchProductView.as_view(), name='search_page'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `get_queryset` method, rather than the class-level `queryset` attribute. This can use your querystring parameters to filter the queryset dynamically.

You haven't shown your search form or said what your parameter is, but assuming it submits a GET parameter named `q`, you would do:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Product.objects.filter(title__icontains=self.request.GET['q'])
```

Comment: I have a GET parameter. Thank you for the answer. This solved my problem. I was confused about the placeholder and I had made a mistake with self.request.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer above will work I believe a better solution would be the following:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)


class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_queryset(self):
    querystr = self.request.GET['q']
    Product.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=querystr) | Q(category__title__icontains=querystr)
    )
```